# Passing value from jsp to Action for java.util.Set

Tags: java, jsp, type-conversion, struts2, ognl

I want to set values for `Set` elements of login from JSP .

**JSP page:**

```
  <form action="Registered" method="post"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Company Name</label>
            <s:textfield name="name" value="%{name}" id="name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <s:textarea name="address" value="%{address}" id="address"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>User Name</label>
            <s:textfield name="logins[0].userName" value="%{logins[0].userName}" id="userName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>User Id</label>
            <s:textfield name="logins[0].userId" value="%{logins[0].userId}" id="userId"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Mail Id</label>
            <s:textfield name="logins[0].userMailid" value="%{logins[0].userMailid}" id="userMailid"/>
        </div>
```

**Pojo Classes:**

```
public class Client  implements java.io.Serializable {
  private Set logins = new HashSet(0);
  //getter and setter
 }



 public class Login implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Client client;
    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String userMailid;
 }
```

**Action Class:**

```
public String register() {
        Client cl = new Client();
        System.out.println(cl.getName() + " " + cl.getAddress());
  }
```

I want to set values of set in to my Action class for Client and Login.

How to do this?

Comment: you want to get value from textfield or you want  set default value in text field?

Comment: User will fill form When form submitted it should assing in client and login fields

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23470075/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191304/876739 Working for set. How can I do that with this code

Comment: What is the requirement to use `Set`? A `List` could be a reasonable replacement.

Comment: @RomanC While using Set it is better with Hibernate( I think). It create problem with list during fetch. If we use multiple list to fetch data it creates problem. So I would like to use Set insted of list

Comment: @xrcwrn Do you have arguments against a `Set`? If you have some unknown problems with it explains nothing. You can elaborate on why you prefer sets over lists.

Comment: @RomanC Ok Not good reasones but still i want to use `Set` because I want to use it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191304/876739 shows how to do that. I am not able to use according to my need. could you please tell me how can I modify my code so it should work

Comment: @xrcwrn I have given you a ways to do that, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24849726/573032).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a submit button like this:

```
 <form action="Registered" method="post"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company Name</label>
                <s:textfield name="name" value="%{name}" id="name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address</label>
                <s:textarea name="address" value="%{address}" id="address"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Name</label>
                <s:textfield name="logins[0].userName" value="%{logins[0].userName}" id="userName"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Id</label>
                <s:textfield name="logins[0].userId" value="%{logins[0].userId}" id="userId"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mail Id</label>
                <s:textfield name="logins[0].userMailid" value="%{logins[0].userMailid}" id="userMailid"/>
            </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

**EDIT**

A nice [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-stextfield-textbox-example/)

After make properties file like:

```
#Global messages
name= name
submit = Submit
```

I believe you has made Registered.jsp.

An you can run your project!

Comment: I forget to add there is also a submit buttom

Comment: In first jsp " <input type="submit" value="Submit">"

Comment: I can edit my answer with Completed example if you want

Comment: I am using struts2 where `String name = request.getParameter("name");` not necessary to get value from jsp

Comment: ok. I didn't know. so you solve your problem or I edit my answer?

Answer (score 0):

To bind fildes to `Set` you should put annotations on this property

```
public class Client  implements java.io.Serializable {

  @Element(value = Login.class)
  @Key(value = Long.class)
  @KeyProperty(value = "id") 
  @CreateIfNull(value = true)
  private Set logins = new HashSet(0);
  //getter and setter

  //now you need a property for login id, it should be initialized before JSP is populated
  private Long loginId;
  //getter and setter
}
```

now binding to the fields of the JSP change to

```
<s:textfield name="logins(%{loginId}).userName" id="userName"/>
```

the same for other fields that are bound to a set.

If you are using iterator tag to iterate through a set and you have an instance of `Login` pushed on top of the value stack then you can get its `id` instead of using `loginId`.